# Window function is not supported in partition by clauses

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

```
select t1.lease_number ,t2.rec_bal, to_date(t2.date_dim_id,'YYYYMMDD') as issue_date,t2.paid_to as pay_date,
(case when pay_date <= lag(pay_date) over (order by issue_date) then null when pay_date > lag(pay_date) over (order by issue_date) then issue_date end) as payment_date,
dense_rank() over (partition by pay_date order by issue_date) as row_numbers,
(case when row_numbers = max(row_numbers) over (partition by payment_date) then payment_date else null end) as paymentmade_date,
remain_months_upd,remaining_pymt_periods, t2.dealer_dim_id, t2.lease_contract_dim_id

from dm_business_ops_tcci.v_tcci_lease_contract_dim t1
, dm_business_ops_tcci.v_tcci_lease_transaction_fact t2

where t1.lease_contract_dim_id=t2.lease_contract_dim_id
and t2.date_dim_id >=20210301 -- can be changed to latest busienss date
and lease_number in (1633014)
order by issue_date
```

I am trying to partition by a column I created using a window function, and I can't do it. The error is coming from the line "(case when row_numbers = max(row_numbers) over (partition by payment_date) then payment_date else null end) as paymentmade_date". Payment_date is calculating using a window function in a prior line.  Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to materialize the values of your window functions before you perform any sort of filtering, partitioning, or conditional operations on that value.

There are a few ways to go about doing this, and the appropriate one for your use case will vary depending factor outside of this scope.

You may accomplish this using a view, CTE, temp table, or a table variable prior to attempting this partitioning operation. This is not an exhaustive list.